# Docker- nginx -Reverse proxy : host not found in upstream when building with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using NGINX container to redirect certain requests to another container.While running docker-compose up -d , i am getting bellow error.

"    **2019/09/26 18:05:00 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "abcplus-visualize:61613" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10
    nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "abcplus-visualize:61613" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10**"

below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
    reverseproxy:
        image: reverseproxy
        ports:
            - 49665:2181
        restart: always

    abcplus-visualize:
        depends_on:
            - reverseproxy
        image: abcplus-visualize:latest
        restart: always
```

below is my nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-abcplus {
        server abcplus-visualize:61613;
    }

    server {
        listen 2181;
        server_name localhost;

          location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-abcplus;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your app listen to `61613` ? you does not specify any port in your `compose`

Comment: @LinPy my app is listening 61613 and i have mentioned 2181 in nginx.conf for mapping with docker compose file. That mapping is already present

Comment: and docker ps shows that the both containers are up ?

Comment: @LinPy Yes in Docker ps ,its showing both the server are up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue with Server name which we are giving in upstream. 
I tried with **abcplus-visualize** instead of **abcplus-visualize** , its working fine. 
May be while starting docker-compose server name with hypen("-") it is not understating.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
upstream docker-abcplus {
    server abcplus-visualize:61613 max_fails=6 fail_timeout=30s;
}
```

I think your `upstream` fails too fast before the `app` is running